# Django - Pass a <select> form POST data from one view to another

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass data that I collected from a  form, onto another page. I am a beginner at Django and still don't understand POST and GET.

I've been trying to solve this issue for the past few days, but I keep running in circles. I am assuming this is a rather simple issue, but I just don't know what's going on.

I want to have it that on my select interest view, once I click on submit will send the selected interest to another view called select discipline. I want to be able to use that selected interest in my select_discipline view.

views.py

```
@login_required
def select_interest(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    interests = Interest.objects.order_by('name')

    return render_to_response('selectinterest.html', {'interests': interests, 'disciplines': disciplines }, context )

@login_required
def select_discipline(request):


    interest = request.POST.get('interest-select')
    context = RequestContext(request)
    interests = Interest.objects.order_by('name')
    disciplines = Discipline.objects.filter(parentInterest = interest)

    return render('selectdiscipline.html', {'interest': interest, 'interests': interests, 'disciplines': disciplines }, context )
```

selectinterest.html

```
<div class = "container">
  <h1>Change Primary Interest</h1>

  <form action="{% url 'myapp:select_discipline' %}" method="POST" id="interest-select">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select title="interest-select" id="usrInterest">
      <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
      {% for i in interests %}
      <option name = "interest" value={{i.id}}>{{i.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}

    </select> -->
    <input type="submit" value="Load Disciplines"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note:  I think the problem is that you did not define 'name' attribute in the select tag. You should use attribute 'name' in the tag select, because,  It is the name used the dictionary POST Also, I recommend using [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms)

selectinterest.html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Change Primary Interest</h1>
  <form action="{% url 'myapp:select_discipline' %}" method="POST" id="interest-select">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="id_interest" name="interest">
      <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
      {% for i in interests %}
      <option value={{i.id}}>{{i.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Load Disciplines"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def select_discipline(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        interest = request.POST.get('interest')
        context = RequestContext(request)
        interests = Interest.objects.order_by('name')
        disciplines = Discipline.objects.filter(parentInterest=interest)

        return render(
            'selectdiscipline.html',
            {
                'interest': interest,
                'interests': interests,
                'disciplines': disciplines
            },
            context
        )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the recommendation!